# vue page does not render changes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localization, internationalization

I have a multilingual site. Using Vue.js & Laravel. However the translated page for vue does not render any changes.

This is my app.js:

```js
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import Locales from './vue-i18n-locales.generated.js';

Vue.use(VueI18n)

const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
    
    ....
```

This is my blade.php file:

```html
<operations baseurl="{{ url('/') }}"
              apiurl="{{ Config('main.apiHostName') }}"
              assignurl="{{ Config('main.apiOrdersAssignUrl') }}"
              updateurl="{{ Config('main.apiOrdersUpdateUrl') }}"
              cancelurl="{{ Config('main.apiOrdersCancelUrl') }}"
              notifyonlineurl="{{ Config('main.apiOrdersNotifyOnlineUrl') }}"
              notifyactiveurl="{{ Config('main.apiOrdersNotifyActiveUrl') }}"
              cid="{{ session('id') }}" csession="{{ session('session') }}"
              default-zoom="11" center-lat="3.182355" center-lng="101.664624"
              Vue.config.lang = '{{ app()->getLocale() }}'>
  </operations>
```

How do I sync Vue & Laravel file (blade.php) to render the other language?

Comment: I don't know the lib you are using but the way I accomplish this is to create one main translation file I called it main let's say my website supports English and Spanish I create en/main & es/main then I will pass it as a props to my vue component from blade which means if the locale was en blade will pass en/main to vue component as a props and in my vue component I can use it as normal javascript object for sure you have to json decode it when pass it from blade so you don't get any errors

Comment: @MohammadIstanboli do you have any tutorial i can refer? i'm using https://github.com/martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator. no errors but the page just wont translate

Comment: Actually I have watched a vue tutorial then with the knowledge I gained I come up with this way I will post answer to your question my way tonight because currently  I am at work okay

Comment: @MohammadIstanboli any updates? :)

Comment: Yeah I will post an example now Sorry for late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me I add translation to Vue component by passing it as props lets say I want to Support Both Arabic and English in my website so here are the steps

First Create the translation files in the lang directory

```
resources/lang/en/main.php    //English Translation
resources/lang/ar/main.php    //Arabic Translation
```

lets say these file returns only one key to be translated so they look like this

English File

```
<?php
//resources/lang/en/main.php

return [
    'greeting' => 'Hello',
];
```

Arabic File

```
<?php
//resources/lang/ar/main.php

return [
    'greeting' => 'مرحبا',
];
```

lets say that you want to be able to use these translation on one of your Vue components for example the `TestComponent.vue` all you have to do is render this component in one of your blade files I will call my blade `test.blade.php`

```
//test.blade.php
.
.
.
<body>
    <div id="app"><!-- app id is for vue js to mount the application here-->

        <!--
            here this is called passing a props to a vue componenet
            this props name is trans since we passed :trans
            and its value is json_encode(trans('main'))
            main is the main.php file we created before Laravel
            will pass the english or arabic based on the current App locale
        -->

        <test-component :trans="{{json_encode(trans('main'))}}"></test-component>
    </div>
</body>
.
.
.
```

Now lets take a look on how to use the translation inside of our `TestComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ trans.greeting }}</h1>
</template>

export default {
    props : ['trans'], // this should be called trans since in blade we passed it as trans
    data(){
        return {

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this explanation helps to solve your problem , Good luck.